# can not find form group in angular when using the promiss

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need create a form after send request to database and get reponse from server and fill form with that data .

i write this code for send request and fill form from that response :

```
  data: any;
  accountSettingFG: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private accountsettingService: AccountSettingService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.FetchData().then(res=>{
        this.InitialForm();
    });


  }


  InitialForm(): void {
    this.accountSettingFG = this.formBuilder.group({
      twoFactorAuthentication: [this.data.twoFactorAuthentication],
      email: [this.data.email],
      sms: [this.data.sms]
    })
  }

  FetchData() {
    let promiss = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.accountsettingService.GetListItem('/SiteOption/AccountSecurity')
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
          this.data= res.result['accountSecuritySettingsModel']
          resolve();
        }, msg => {
          reject(msg);
        })
    })
    return promiss;
  }
```

and this is my `Html Code :`

```
   <form
      class="form"
      id="postform"
      [formGroup]="accountSettingFG"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
      autocomplete="off"
    >

      <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" formControlName="twoFactorAuthentication">
        {{ "SETTING.ACCOUNT_SCURITY.TOW_FACTOR_ACUTHENTICATION" | translate }}
      </mat-slide-toggle>

      <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" formControlName="email">
        {{ "SETTING.ACCOUNT_SCURITY.EMAIL" | translate }}
      </mat-slide-toggle>

      <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" formControlName="sms">
        {{ "SETTING.ACCOUNT_SCURITY.SMS" | translate }}
      </mat-slide-toggle>
  
    </form>
```

but when i run the project it show me this error :

> ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

```
   Example:

   
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
at Function.missingFormException (forms.js:2283)
at FormGroupDirective._checkFormPresent (forms.js:7490)
at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7280)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:33257)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:46077)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:46016)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:47039)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:46982)
at Object.updateDirectives (account-option.component.html:3)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:46970)
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: In the initial rendering the form group will not be created yet since the request is still pending and not resolved. Therefore, `this.accountSettingFG` is not set and leads to the seen error. One solution would be to not show this component at all until the data has resolved.

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt how can i do this ? i can not use the reolve in route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest initialising the form with empty values before sending the request. This should avoid the issue. Therefore, you need to update the form when your response is received.

I'm not familiar with Angular > 1. Might be that it's introducing other issues. Anyway, I hope it helps.

```
  data: any;
  accountSettingFG: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private accountsettingService: AccountSettingService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accountSettingFG = this.formBuilder.group({
      twoFactorAuthentication: [''],
      email: [''],
      sms: ['']
    });

    this.FetchData().then(res => {
        this.InitialForm();
    });
  }

  InitialForm(): void {
    this.accountSettingFG.setValue(this.data);
  }

  FetchData() {
      return this.accountsettingService.GetListItem('/SiteOption/AccountSecurity')
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
          return res.result['accountSecuritySettingsModel'];
        })
  }
```